# how to solve Class 'Admin_Controller' not found in /home/webpage/public_html/appage/application/controllers/admin/Adminpanel.php on line 4?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am developing web application in codeigniter . The below code is working fine in my localhost (i am using xampp as localhost). But when i uploaded it in my web server it showing error like,

> Fatal error:how to solve Class 'Admin_Controller' not found in
>   /home/webpage/public_html/appage/application/controllers/admin/Adminpanel.php
>   on line 4

I am extending controller from core file.

My core controller is,

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class My_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
       parent::__construct();

    }
}
class Admin_Controller extends My_Controller
{
   public function __construct()
    {
       parent::__construct();

    }

}
class User_Controller extends My_Controller
{
  public function __construct()
    {
       parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

And my controller files under controller is,While trying to  access it show error as what i mentioned above,

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Adminpanel extends Admin_Controller{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

    }
}
```

it showing error like,

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/webpage/public_html/appage/application/controllers/admin/Adminpanel.php:4)
>
> Filename: core/Common.php
>
> Line Number: 568
>
> Backtrace:
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Error
>
> Message: Class 'Admin_Controller' not found
>
> Filename: admin/Adminpanel.php
>
> Line Number: 4
>
> Backtrace:

Please any to help me to solve this issue,

Comment: once try by creating separate files for each class in your core. also make sure that your extended `CI_Controller` is either  `My_Controller` or `MY_Controller`

Comment: Thank you very much for you replay. I extended as My_Controller from CI_Controller. That controller name is My_Controller.php

Comment: ok  did u tried creating separate file for each class??

Comment: Thank you very much after changing from My_Controller to MY_Controller its working.